# Circle Overlay is not showing on map

Tags: ios, dictionary, overlay

I am trying to add a circle overlay to a map, but it is not appearing:

```
- (void) displayOverlayOnMap:(double) lat andlng: (double)  lng
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D bostonCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat,lng);
    //add MKCircle overlay...
    MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:bostonCoord radius:1000];
   [self.mapView addOverlay:circle]; 
}
```

Any body have a clue why it's not showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is an example.. you can also find one using polygons on apple's sites:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW15

or you can use this example

[Create overlay from user interaction on MKMapView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223195/create-overlay-from-user-interaction-on-mkmapview)

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
        return;

    CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:mapView];    
    CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate = [mapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:mapView];

    //add pin where user touched down...
    MKPointAnnotation *pa = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    pa.coordinate = touchMapCoordinate;
    pa.title = @"Hello";
    [mapView addAnnotation:pa];
    [pa release];

    //add circle with 5km radius where user touched down...
    MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:touchMapCoordinate radius:5000];
    [mapView addOverlay:circle];
}

-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id)overlay 
{
    MKCircleView* circleView = [[[MKCircleView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay] autorelease];
    circleView.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return circleView;
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *AnnotationIdentifier = @"Annotation";
    MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
    if (!pinView)
    {
        pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return pinView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code

```
CLLocationDistance radiusInMeters = 1000;
MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:bostonCoord radius:radiusInMeters];
```

Instead of

```
MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:bostonCoord radius:1000];
```

It worked for me.